# p:autocomplete primefaces actualizar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo el siguiente componente de primefaces:

```
<p:autoComplete widgetVar="instalacion_w" size="52" dropdown="true" id="instalacion" scrollHeight="300" maxResults="100" value="#{facturacionView.filters.instalacion}" completeMethod="#{facturacionView.getInstalacion}"
    var="item" itemLabel="#{item.value}" itemValue="#{item.key}" forceSelection="true" multiple="true" queryDelay="1000" cache="true" cacheTimeout="60000" emptyMessage="Ningun dato coincide">                         
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"  listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}"  update="" onstart="PF('cargando').show()" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide()" />
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}" update="" onstart="PF('cargando').show()" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide()" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

Imaginemos que el componente se carga con los siguientes elementos:

> Texto1; Texto2; Texto3; Texto4.

Si el usuario selecciona por ejemplo `Texto1`, mediante: `<p:ajax event="itemSelect"  listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}"` Elimino el objeto seleccionado.

El problema viene a que ese elemento se sigue viendo en el p:autoComplete, hasta que se vuelve a llamar a `completeMethod`.

¿Existe alguna manera de forzar al `p:autoComplete` se actualice?

PrimeFaces 6.1. Mojarra 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` indica elementos a refrescar desde el cliente.

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect"  listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}"  update="@this" onstart="PF('cargando').show()" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide()" />
```

Comment: me lanza la excepcion javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: itemValue="#{item.key}": Propiedad 'key' no hallada en el tipo java.lang.String

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver, eso dice que los ítems (o al menos uno de los ítems) que `completeMethod="#{facturacionView.getInstalacion}"` devuelve no tienen un método `getKey()`

Comment: Acabo de comprobar los registros y antes de la excepcion tiene toda la informacion, getKey y getValue. ¿Puede que necesite hacer algún Converter? Veo algun ejemplo en el que en lugar de `itemValue="#{item.key}"` usan `itemValue="#{item}"` Pero me dice que no es de tipo String.

Comment: El converter funciona en sentido inverso; cuando seleccionas un valor (que en HTML será un String) te lo convierte automáticamente a propiedades String, int, etc. pero si la conversión es más complicada (obtener un bean en función de su clave) entonces necesitas el converter. El mensaje de error indica lo que te digo, se está encontrando un `String` e intenta llamar a un método `getKey()`. Lo que tambien puede que venga de `value="#{facturacionView.filters.instalacion}" `

Comment: Al final era por el atributo cache="true", y sin update! Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre recomiendo actualizar por ***styleClass*** cuando un update por id no funciona, de esta forma:

```
<p:autoComplete styleClass="instalacion" dropdown="true">                         
<p:ajax event="itemSelect"  listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}"  update="@(.instalacion)" onstart="PF('cargando').show()" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide()" />
<p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{facturacionView.instalacionSelected}" update="@(.instalacion)" onstart="PF('cargando').show()" oncomplete="PF('cargando').hide()" />
```

Es más sencillo, ademas no necesitas ir especificando los padres de los id's (catalog_form:algun_div:otro_div:id) simplemente va directo al tag que contenga el styleClass.